# Multi-dimensional array - uasort has no effect, usort removes keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Kind of complex sorting requirement.
Data looks like this:

```
array (size=238)
527 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Ms. Sandra Stokes I' (length=19)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 1
      'meta_data_id' => int 28151
      'person_id' => int 527
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Ms. Sandra Stokes I' (length=19)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 22
      'meta_data_id' => int 28418
      'person_id' => int 527
766 => 
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Rhett Eichmann' (length=14)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 1
      'meta_data_id' => int 28251
      'person_id' => int 766
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Rhett Eichmann' (length=14)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 10
      'meta_data_id' => int 28272
      'person_id' => int 766
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Rhett Eichmann' (length=14)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 19
      'meta_data_id' => int 28378
      'person_id' => int 766
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Rhett Eichmann' (length=14)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 20
      'meta_data_id' => int 28213
      'person_id' => int 766
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Rhett Eichmann' (length=14)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 22
      'meta_data_id' => int 28869
      'person_id' => int 766
  5 => 
    array (size=5)
      'person_name' => string 'Rhett Eichmann' (length=14)
      'archive_id' => int 1
      'archive_item_id' => int 28
      'meta_data_id' => int 28135
      'person_id' => int 766
```

Comparison function used:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            if ($a[0]['person_name'] == $b[0]['person_name'])
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a[0]['person_name'] < $b[0]['person_name']) ? -1 : 1;
        }            

        usort($data, "cmp");
```

With usort, the return is arranged in alphabetical order of person first name,
like so, but stripping off the id index:

```
"person_ids": [
    [
        {
            "person_name": "Abner Becker",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 2,
            "meta_data_id": 28376,
            "person_id": 538
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "person_name": "Addie Legros",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 8,
            "meta_data_id": 28365,
            "person_id": 606
        },
        {
            "person_name": "Addie Legros",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 20,
            "meta_data_id": 28594,
            "person_id": 606
        },
        {
            "person_name": "Addie Legros",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 21,
            "meta_data_id": 28405,
            "person_id": 606
        }
    ],
```

With uasort, the keys are preserved but the function does not seem to be invoked.

```
{
"person_ids": {
    "502": [
        {
            "person_name": "Mr. Tara Bartoletti",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 15,
            "meta_data_id": 28247,
            "person_id": 502
        }
    ],
    "503": [
        {
            "person_name": "Stacy Adams",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 8,
            "meta_data_id": 28918,
            "person_id": 503
        },
        {
            "person_name": "Stacy Adams",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 22,
            "meta_data_id": 28682,
            "person_id": 503
        },
        {
            "person_name": "Stacy Adams",
            "archive_id": 1,
            "archive_item_id": 26,
            "meta_data_id": 28148,
            "person_id": 503
        }
    ],
    "504": [
```

Any advice on how to accomplish sorting by the person_name key while maintaining the id key?

Answer (score 2):

Wow - the culprit was in Postman's "pretty" view, it re-sorts all the keys when viewing JSON! That was a fun 2 hour circle.

Answer (score 1):

You should just sort the sub arrays like below:

```
foreach ($array as $id => &$sub_array) {
  usort($sub_array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['person_name'], $b['person_name']);
  });
}
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I tried this function but it did not have any effect either. Perhaps it's because person name has an extra array dimension?

Comment: I'm running 5.4. Just to be clear, we're trying to sort in alphabetical order by person_name, though within a single id there might be an array of several items that have the same name.

Comment: @egekhter Could you just post the sample data then I could make an example for you.

Comment: @egekhter The php code with `$array = array(...` could run please, and I will give you the result.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I debugged your code and $sub_array always has the same person_name. The expected result is what I listed as the result with the usort function, however it stripped the id index.